# Django website not returning any data when using DNS

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, mezzanine

I have a simple Django website running on a Digital Ocean instance. I configured my DNS provider to point my URL to the Digital Ocean instance's IP address. When I enter that IP address in a browser everything works as expected but when I use the URL I get the correct site but no data is presented.

The site was created using Mezzanine, running on nginx and using postgres as a database.
What could be wrong? I'm not sure where/how to troubleshoot this error.

Comment: What does your webserver (eg nginx) configuration look like? Is it listening on that address?

Comment: have you tried to do `nslookup yourwebsite.com` and verify the output with your Digital ocean Ip address If the Ip matches, DNS is configured correctly.

Comment: @ManojGautam yes I have, the URL _is_ pointing to the correct IP address.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Would it even respond if it wasn't ?

Comment: If the URL is pointing to correct IP, Verify your web server configuration file, Which web server are you using ? `Apache or Nginx` Is the web server configuration file pointing to the correct web directory ? verify the project directory in your web server configuration file.

Comment: @ManojGautam it's nginx, I have updated the question accordingly

Comment: What do you see, when your request the page with wget or curl?

Comment: If you are using `nginx` this link can help you, as you are using Digital Ocean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @OlafDietsche `wget` and `curl` just give me the same results as a browser. Although it's really weird and seems to have something to do with caching, now when I go to the website's IP using chrome (incognito, and hard reload and empty cache) I get no data, but doing the same using Firefox yields all the data I am expecting. I am completely baflled and have no idea what could be causing such a weird behavior

Comment: Look into the web server log files. Maybe there's a hint what is really happening.

Comment: Do you have `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`in your django config?

Comment: @serg no I don't but I did have some old ip addresses in there and even another url I was planning to use, do you think that could have any effect?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to try if there are no other ideas, unless you have your new domain listed there django won't respond (putting `*` there would just disable host check).